# Need change perl code on pure shell. Parse file and change ENVs

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I want change that piece of code: 
`$(perl -p -e 's/\$(\w+)/("$ENV{$1}")/eg' < file_with_html)`

And do parsing and changing without perl
`file_with_html`: contains html template, for example

```
      <th class='xtr-0-0'>Version name</th>
      <td class='xtr-0-1'>$RELEASE_TAG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='xtr-1'>
      <th class='xtr-1-0'>Link</th>
      <td class='xtr-1-1'>$RELEASE_URL</td>...
```

I need change all 
$(\w+) on ENVs with same name and send that "parsed" template to POST request.
How i can do that with grep/sed/awk/etc ?

UPD1: 
I send POST with curl

Fullscript, that generates new page in Confluence:

```
newPageTemplate=$(perl -p -e 's/\$(\w+)/("$ENV{$1}")/eg' < $CONFLUENCE_PAGE_TEMPLATE)

newPageContent="{
    \"type\": \"page\",
    \"title\": \"$CONFLUENCE_PAGE_TITLE\",
    \"ancestors\": [
        {
            \"id\": \"$CONFLUENCE_PARENTPAGE_ID\"
        }
    ],
    \"space\": {
        \"key\": \"$CONFLUENCE_SPACE\"
    },
    \"body\": {
        \"storage\": {
            \"value\": \"$(echo ${newPageTemplate})\",
            \"representation\": \"storage\"
        }
    }
}"
curl --request POST \
--url $CONFLUENCE_API_URL \
--header "authorization: Basic $JIRA_TOKEN" \
--header "content-type: application/json" \
--data "$newPageContent"
```

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Then why did you tag it with Perl?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What have you tried?

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given that output. YMMV if you're relying on us being able to read that perl script to figure out **exactly** what it is you need to output.

Comment: What POST request? Are you running shell scripts in your web server? Why?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original perl is much simpler but it can probably be done in awk.

Perl's `\w` matches slightly more than `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` (see: https://metacpan.org/pod/perlrecharclass#Word-characters) but I'll assume that's all that will appear in an environment variable name (which also cannot begin with a digit).

### POSIX AWK

```
awk '
    {
        n = split( $0, f, /[^$0-9a-zA-Z_]+/ )
        for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
            v = f[i]
            if ( v ~ /^[$][a-zA-Z_]/ ) {
                sub( /^[$]/, "", v )
                sub( "[$]"v, ENVIRON[v] )
            }
        }
    }
    1
' file_with_html
```

- `split` extracts potential environment variable references
- `v ~ /.../` matches just the valid ones
- first `sub` removes the leading `$`
- second `sub` replaces the `$` with appropriate escaping and replaces the variable reference with the value (if any)
- `1` prints every line

**Warning:** The code above has a subtle bug. In the pathological case where a line needs multiple substitutions and the value of one looks like a reference to a subsequent one, because the substitutions do not happen simultaneously, the wrong part of the line will be changed. Eg. If `A='$B'; B='x';` and line contains: `.. $A .. $B ..`, output will be `.. x .. $B ..` and not `.. $B .. x ...`

### GNU GAWK

The bug can be fixed if `gawk` extensions are used. For example, with `patsplit`:

```
gawk '
   {
      if (n = patsplit($0, f, "[$][a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]*", s)) {
         printf "%s", s[0]
         for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
            sub( /^[$]/, "", f[i] )
            printf "%s%s", ENVIRON[ f[i] ], s[i]
         }
         printf "\n"
      }
      else print
   }
' file_with_html
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

**I need change all $(\w+) on ENVs with same name. How i can do that with grep/sed/awk/etc?**

First, `grep`, `sed`, and `awk` are not "pure shell".  Those are commands installed on the system -- just like `perl` is.  If you can install `perl`, I recommend it; it's terribly useful.  If not, your next best approach might be copying the source files to a machine where you *can* install `perl`, and running the process as-is, since the end result is to POST the results back to Confluence (i.e., you can POST from off-system).

But, if you really, absolutely cannot use `perl`, of course there is a way to do this with other text-processing tools like `grep`, `sed`, and `awk`.

Second, what have you tried so far?  Stack Overflow works best when you show us what you've done so far, what works, and in what ways it doesn't work.  That helps people focus their responses according to your exact problem and tailored to your current understanding.

Third, here is a script that might guide you.  Again, I don't know how much `bash` your know, so this might be a bit obscure.  It's also certainly not the only way to do this, and quite probably not the best.  I highly recommend testing this by running it on a few sample pages and inspecting the output before POST'ing it; tools like `diff` or `vimdiff` will help a lot here.  Then, even when you are ready to actually POST the results, start slowly with a subset, and validate the results before opening up the firehose.

---

### **WARNING: the below script breaks under common circumstances**

As noted by @jhnc in the comments, the `sed` command will fail when the replacement text contains characters that are replacement-metacharacters for `sed` (such as '/' in a URL).  There is a way to compensate with further script logic, but IMHO down that path lies madness.

**My recommendation if `perl` cannot be installed on the target machine is my "next best approach" that I mentioned above:** copy the input data to a machine where you *can* run `perl`, and run the transformation and POST back to Confluence from there.

But also take a look at the answer from @jhnc, which offers a solution that avoids this weakness in mine.

*(I'm placing this warning here instead of deleting my answer, because of the simpler solutions above, and in case this approach serves as a basis for someone who wishes to improve upon it.)*

**USE THE BELOW APPROACH WITH A GREAT DEAL OF CAUTION**

---

**replace-env-params.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r LINE; do

    MATCH=$(echo "$LINE" | grep -E '\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+')
    if [[ ! -z "$MATCH" ]]; then
        ENVPARAM=$(echo "$LINE" | sed 's/^.*\$\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\).*$/\1/')

        ENVVAL="$ENVPARAM"
        REPLACE="${!ENVVAL}"

        LINE=$(echo "$LINE" | sed "s/\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/$REPLACE/")
    fi

    echo "$LINE"

done < $1
```

**cat somehtml**

```
      <th class='xtr-0-0'>Version name</th>
      <td class='xtr-0-1'>$RELEASE_TAG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='xtr-1'>
      <th class='xtr-1-0'>Link</th>
      <td class='xtr-1-1'>$RELEASE_URL</td>
```

**testing ...**

```
export RELEASE_TAG=11111111
export RELEASE_URL=22222222

./replace-env-params.sh somehtml

      <th class='xtr-0-0'>Version name</th>
      <td class='xtr-0-1'>11111111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='xtr-1'>
      <th class='xtr-1-0'>Link</th>
      <td class='xtr-1-1'>22222222</td>
```

Thus, you can replace:

```
newPageTemplate=$(perl -p -e 's/\$(\w+)/("$ENV{$1}")/eg' < $CONFLUENCE_PAGE_TEMPLATE)
```

with

```
newPageTemplate=$(./replace-env-params.sh $CONFLUENCE_PAGE_TEMPLATE)
```

Comment: 1) sed will barf if REPLACE contains special characters; 2) your code doesn't handle multiple variables on a single line

Comment: @jhnc : both of those are fair points, and to that extent yes, my solution does not fully emulate the perl being replaced; for the use-case at hand, that might or might not matter; e.g., have you ever seen an environment variable name with anything other than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`?  while other characters are legal, I've never seen it done; and from contextual clues, I'd give good odds that in the actual data, a given line has only one environment variable; I'm not disagreeing with you, but speaking pragmatically, this solution might be "good enough"

Comment: @Zash : regarding the comment here from jhnc, if your actual data does in fact have some lines with more than one `$THING_TO_REPLACE`, you can (1) use my script as-is and run a multipass for those input templates, (2) adapt my script as necessary, or (3) let me know and I'll take a crack at adapting it; thx!

Comment: I'm talking about the value of the variable, not the name. For example, a url is likely to contain `/` so the sed command becomes  `s/.../.../.../ `

Comment: @jhnc : oh, I see what you are saying; that's an excellent point; thank you for catching that and taking the time to point it out; I will update my answer with a warning

Comment: @jhnc : now that I see that you have also provided an answer (I didn't scroll far enough before), I will also edit my answer to refer to yours